# Is object deep-compare possible with Spock Framework?

Tags: groovy, equality, spock

How do I check for deep object equality with spock.

Lets say we have a super simple test that compares to identical person objects

```
def "A persons test"() {
    setup:
    def person1 = new Person("Foo", new Address("Bar"))
    def person2 = new Person("Foo", new Address("Bar"))

    expect:
    person1 == person2
}
```

The test fails

```
Condition not satisfied:

person1 == person2
|       |  |
|       |  Person@6bedbc4d
|       false
Person@57af006c
```

This looks like a very natural way of asserting equality.

One of the main reason to start using spock was to avoid having to write a lot of hamcrest boilerplate matchers code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spock has no built-in mechanism for performing deep Object comparison, because defining object equality is out of scope of any testing framework. You can do a various things.

#### 1. Both classes are Groovy classes

If both your classes (`Person` and `Address`) are Groovy classes you can generate `equals` and `hashCode` methods using `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation over both classes, like:

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
import spock.lang.Specification

class PersonSpec extends Specification {

    def "a person test"() {
        setup:
        def person1 = new Person("Foo", new Address("Bar"))
        def person2 = new Person("Foo", new Address("Bar"))

        expect:
        person1 == person2
    }

    @TupleConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    static class Person {
        String name
        Address address
    }

    @TupleConstructor
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    static class Address {
        String city
    }
}
```

This is just a convenient alternative for implementing both methods in Groovy.

#### 2. Both classes are Java classes

If you want to compare both objects with `==` operator then you will have to define `equals` and `hashCode` methods in both classes, something like:

```
public final class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final Address address;

    public Person(String name, Address address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (name != null ? !name.equals(person.name) : person.name != null) return false;
        return address != null ? address.equals(person.address) : person.address == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    static class Address {
        private final String city;

        public Address(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

            Address address = (Address) o;

            return city != null ? city.equals(address.city) : address.city == null;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return city != null ? city.hashCode() : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example both methods were defined using IntelliJ IDEA "Generate equals and hashCode" command.

#### 3. I can use Lombok!

If you don't want to define both methods manually (because e.g. you have to remember to change them anytime you modify your class fields) then you can use [Lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) that does something similar to Groovy's annotation, but can be applied to any Java class.

#### 4. I want to keep default `equals` and `hashCode` methods

Well, in this case you can try various things:

1. You can try comparing both objects field-by-field, like:

   ```
   class PersonSpec extends Specification {

       def "a person test"() {
           setup:
           def person1 = new Person("Foo", new Address("Bar"))
           def person2 = new Person("Foo", new Address("Bar"))

           expect:
           person1.name == person2.name

           and:
           person1.address.city == person2.address.city
       }

       @TupleConstructor
       static class Person {
           String name
           Address address
       }

       @TupleConstructor
       static class Address {
           String city
       }
   }
   ```
2. You can try using 3rd party tools like [Unitils reflection assertion](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-reflectionassert.html)
3. That may sound bizarre, but you can compare JSON representation of both objects, something like:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonOutput
   import groovy.transform.TupleConstructor
   import spock.lang.Specification

   class PersonSpec extends Specification {

       def "a person test"() {
           setup:
           def person1 = new Person("Foo", new Address("Bar"))
           def person2 = new Person("Foo", new Address("Bar"))

           expect:
           new JsonOutput().toJson(person1) == new JsonOutput().toJson(person2)
       }

       @TupleConstructor
       static class Person {
           String name
           Address address
       }

       @TupleConstructor
       static class Address {
           String city
       }
   }
   ```

Anyway, I would definitely suggest defining `equals` and `hashCode` in one way or another and simply use `==` operator. Hope it helps.

Comment: In option 1, you can just use [`@Canonical`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Canonical.html) instead of `@EqualsAndHashCode` + `@TupleConstructor` + the important `@ToString` which you should also have in these data classes.

Comment: For 4.1, you can use `with` to make the test less _dotty_ http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#specs-as-doc

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, although not what I was hoping for;)

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of Groovy's succinct map comparison syntax:

```
person1.properties == person2.properties
```

That only works for simple flat objects, not nested ones. You could adapt it like so:

```
person1.properties << ['address': person1.address.properties] == person2.properties << ['address': person2.address.properties]
```

...but JSON solution is more elegant at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you use Assertj for deep assertions. See below an example:

```
def "labels1 should be deeply equal to labels2"() {
        when:
        def labels1 = [new Label("labelA"), new Label("labelB")]
        def labels2 = [new Label("labelB"), new Label("labelA")]

        then:
        assertThat(labels1)
                .usingRecursiveComparison()
                .ignoringCollectionOrder()
                .isEqualTo(labels2)
    }
```

Don't forget to add the Gradle dependency:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you need to correct override your equals and hashcode methods.
In Groovy it can be done really easily, you need to use @Canonical annotation. It gives you more than equals and hashcode, buy the way.